# Material UI: Getting values from augmented theme with typescript "keyof"

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm relatively new to typescript and i can't get a solution to the following problem:
I augmented my material Ui theme with the following types:

```
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
  interface Palette {
    customColors: CustomColors;
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    customColors: CustomColors;
  }

  interface CustomColors {
    userColors: UserColors;
    listFiltersBg?: string;
  }

  interface UserColors {
    ROPRIETOR: Color;
    ASSOCIATE: Color;
    MASTER: Color;
    JOURNEYMAN_QUALIFIED: Color;
    JOURNEYMAN_GRADUATED: Color;
    JOURNEYMAN_TRAINED: Color;
    LABORER: Color;
    OFFICEWORKER: Color;
  }
}



const theme = createMuiTheme(
    {
      palette: {
        type: darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
        customColors: {
          userColors: {
            ROPRIETOR: colors.green,
            ASSOCIATE: colors.lightGreen,
            MASTER: colors.pink,
            JOURNEYMAN_QUALIFIED: colors.deepPurple,
            JOURNEYMAN_GRADUATED: colors.purple,
            JOURNEYMAN_TRAINED: colors.indigo,
            LABORER: colors.teal,
            OFFICEWORKER: colors.lime,
          },
          listFiltersBg: colors.grey[200],
        },
      },
    },
    deDE,
  );
```

but when i try to get the color based on a dynamic value i always get undefined instead of the corresponding color object:

```
export const getUserColor: GetUserColor = (position = 'PROPRIETOR', { palette }, ) => {
  const userColor = palette.customColors.userColors[position as keyof UserColors];

  console.log('USER_COLOR', userColor); // logs "undefined"

  return usercolor[500];
  
};
```

what am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Instead of `position as keyof UserColors`, use the arguments to enforce that `position` must be a valid key: `position: keyof UsersColors = 'PROPRIETOR'`.  And already we see one error because the key is `ROPRIETOR` not `PROPRIETOR`.  Is that it?  I suspect there are more errors lurking.

Comment: My next question would be where you are calling `getUserColor`, how you're retrieving the value of `palette` which you pass in, and whether that variable looks like what it's supposed to.

Comment: When you're getting the `palette` from a theme argument you can type that like: `({palette}: {palette: Palette})` (we don't care about any other properties of the theme), or you could pass in `theme.palette` directly as `(palette: Palette)`.

Comment: Thx Linda, you were right - it was a typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion: Be aware of typos!! Read your variable-names backwards if you're not sure - otherwise you're brain fills in the missing letter - at least mine does that!